# react + django deployment, the problem is static files 404 error

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment

I've tried to deploy django project using react as front-end.
I did 'npm run build' in react and i moved all the files builded to 'client' folder in django project like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLuU1.png)

And i changed all the 'href' in 'link' and 'script' tags to ./ like

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
<script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.a1de6b00.js"></script>
```

in index.html in 'client' folder.

in the setting.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I changed dirs of templates and

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client/static')
]

DEBUG = False
```

I also changed static root and staticfiles_dirs and debug

and in mysite/url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I added a line of code for ''

But when i run 'python manage.py runserver', it seems there is still problems to load static files like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka4qB.png)
Can you guys let me know what to solve the problems?

Answer (score 0):

I've observed that your Django project has `DEBUG` set to `False`, but it appears you're running on a development server based on the screenshot. In a development environment, it's essential to set `DEBUG = True`; otherwise, static files may not be found.

If you've deployed your project to production, you need to execute `python manage.py collectstatic` to manage static files appropriately.

You can leverage Django's `{% static %}` template tag to dynamically generate URLs for your static files. Here's an improved version:

```html
{% load static %}


<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" />
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'manifest.json' %}" />
<script defer="defer" src="{% static 'js/main.a1de6b00.js' %}"></script>
```

This way, the `{% static %}` template tag will handle the correct URL for your static files, making your HTML more flexible and adaptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And is there codes to change in url.py? because i feel like i should add code to link static files

Comment: No need to change the urls.py file, Django does that for you if you set DEBUG = True in development. Once you deploy to production and run python manage.py collect static, Django also handles that for you. I added improvements on how to leverage Django’s static template tags. Let me know once you try this.

Comment: I've tried but error 500 occur. and i let 'debug = False' because i prepare it to deploy to production

Comment: Do you get a 500 in production or locally? Can you please paste me the full error so I can advise. Did you add {% load static %} to the top of the html where you’re using the {% static %} tags? Check my answer.

Comment: I got 500 error locally, and i didn't add {% load static %}. actually i use react as front-end service so i didn't really know django template tags, i will try and i will let you know

Comment: I added {% load static %}, so error 500 deson't occur anymore. But still it doesn't find static files like                                                                                              
[31/Oct/2023 10:06:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2920
[31/Oct/2023 10:06:46] "GET /static/js/main.d39b2fe2.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[31/Oct/2023 10:06:46] "GET /static/css/main.b3f4d584.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[31/Oct/2023 10:06:46] "GET /static/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 179

Comment: It is because DEBUG = False. You can change it to DEBUG = True and test locally first. Then when you’re sure it is working properly, you can change to DEBUG = False and once deployed you run python manage.py collectstatic. You can checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/ to understand better how Django handles static files

Comment: Yes, i will do debug = true first, and have to find a way how to deploy with debug = false. Thank you for kind answers !

Comment: You can use environmental variables. You create a .env file in your local with DEBUG=True and then in your server with DEBUG=False. So you will just need to update your settings file to set DEBUG using the environment variable. Check this out to know how to do this. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html